# Remove querystring parameters from image src

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to remove any tracing reference from an image.
For example:

```
<img class="pixel" src="pixel.gif?tracking=123456">
<img src="pixel1.gif?t=654321">
```

I would like to remove everything from all image in a email body after the question mark. And I would like to do it with Regex And Replace like this:

```
Regex rRemScript = new Regex(@"??< The part i would like help with >???");
messageBody = rRemScript.Replace(messageBody, "");
```

So I need help with the Regex part for finding all <image src and get everyting after "?".

End result:

```
<img class="pixel" src="pixel.gif">
<img src="pixel1.gif">
```

Comment: If I understand correctly: you would like to wait till the page loads and then remove src details (with javascript)?

Comment: No, before I save the messagebody to database I would like to "clean" the message. I also remove styling, but that part i have solved

Comment: You can easily do it with a combination of `string.IndexOf` and `string.replace`, but with Regex I can't help you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex from the following code:

```csharp
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   var input = @"balbla <img class=""pixel"" src=""pixel.gif?tracking=123456"">
<img src=""pixel1.gif?t=654321"" class=""pixel1""> blablabla";

   var regex = new Regex("(<img[^>]*)src=\"([^\"?]*)?[^\"]*\"");

   // test
   var r = regex.Replace(input, "$1src=\"$2\"");

   var expected = @"balbla <img class=""pixel"" src=""pixel.gif"">
<img src=""pixel1.gif"" class=""pixel1""> blablabla";

   Assert.AreEqual(expected, r);

}
```

Explanation of regex parts:

`(<img[^>]*)src=\"`: Match on `img` tags till their `src` attribute. Save matched part via `()` for backreferencing in replace call later.

`([^\"?]*)`: get the uri part till the first `?`. Save it for backreferencing.

`[^\"]*\"`: get the remaining part of the uri.

Replace it with `$1src=\"$2\"`, where the `$1` contains the first, the `$2` the second saved backreference.